# Fading script will not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm pretty new to Javascript and have been trying to achieve some fading effects on a website.
I've managed to hammer together the effects I want and everything's working fine on Firefox & Safari. However IE doesn't like it. The first script to change the background colour works but the second script to fade in the content does nothing.

I'm calling the scripts from the head as follows:

```
window.onload=siteIntro;
```

And the Javacript which is not working is here. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, the [live site](http://sketchhair.com) can be viewed if needed.

Many Thanks

```
// ################# Fade Divs ###############################

function Fade(objID,CurrentAlpha,TargetAlpha,steps){

    var obj = document.getElementById(objID);

    CurrentAlpha = parseInt(CurrentAlpha);
    if (isNaN(CurrentAlpha)){
        CurrentAlpha = parseInt(obj.style.opacity*100);
        if (isNaN(CurrentAlpha))CurrentAlpha=100;
    }
    var DeltaAlpha=parseInt((CurrentAlpha-TargetAlpha)/steps);
    var NewAlpha = CurrentAlpha - DeltaAlpha;

    if (NewAlpha == 100 && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') == -1)) NewAlpha = 99.99;

    obj.style.opacity = (NewAlpha / 100);
    obj.style.MozOpacity = obj.style.opacity;
    obj.style.KhtmlOpacity = obj.style.opacity;
    obj.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+NewAlpha+')';

    if (steps>1){
        setTimeout('Fade("'+objID+'",'+NewAlpha+','+TargetAlpha+','+(steps-1)+')', 50);
    }
}

// ################# Toggle content div visibility ###############################
function mainVis(showMain) {
    document.getElementById(showMain).style.visibility ="visible";
}

function pageSwitch(show0, hide0, hide1, hide2, hide3) {
    document.getElementById(show0).style.visibility ="visible";
    document.getElementById(hide0).style.visibility ="hidden";
    document.getElementById(hide1).style.visibility ="hidden";
    document.getElementById(hide2).style.visibility ="hidden";
    document.getElementById(hide3).style.visibility ="hidden";
}

function pg1() {
    pageSwitch('prices', 'icon', 'about', 'map', 'news');
    Fade('prices','0',100,30)
}
function pg2() {
    pageSwitch('about', 'icon', 'prices', 'map', 'news');
    Fade('about','0',100,30)
}
function pg3() {
    pageSwitch('map', 'icon', 'about', 'prices', 'news');
    Fade('map','0',100,30)
}
function pg4() {
    pageSwitch('news', 'icon', 'map', 'about', 'prices');
    Fade('news','0',100,30)
}

// ################# Site Intro Functions ###############################

function siteIntro() {
    setTimeout("NLBfadeBg('b1','#FFFFFF','#000000','3000')",2000);
    mainVis('main');
    setTimeout("Fade('main','',100,30)",5000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS filters only apply to elements that "have layout".

To force layout, you can give the element a `width` or a `height`, or use the old `zoom: 1;` trick.

Not sure if this is the cause of your problems, but you could try it.

You can read more about `hasLayout` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481(VS.85).aspx).

Another thing, instead of:

```
setTimeout('Fade("'+objID+'",'+NewAlpha+','+TargetAlpha+','+(steps-1)+')', 50)`
```

you can simply write:

```
setTimeout(function() { Fade(objID, NewAlpha, TargetAlpha, steps-1); }, 50)`
```

Unless you are doing it just for fun and/or learning, just use an existing JS library instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: That's it! Had missed out the height!!! You're a star...
And yes I know there are probably easier ways, but I'm trying to learn whats going on rather tahn reling on out-of-the-box stuff.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take advantage of an out-of-the-box cross browser script like this
http://brainerror.net/scripts/javascript/blendtrans/

Or use jQuery (which is great with animating and effects) or any other JS library

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer you are looking for, but you shouldn't be doing this: you can use jQuery to do this for you. One or two lines of code, and it is cross browser compatible.